# echo campo columna repetida

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando una consulta sql con LEFT JOIN, el asunto es que ambas tablas tienen una columna de nombre Id y yo necesito imprimir el Id de una de las tablas, ¿como se hace esto?. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea alias en tus resultados select 
esta pagina te ayudara con esto 
http://www.ite.educacion.es/formacion/materiales/93/cd/m6/cambiar_el_nombre_de_los_campos_en_el_resultado_con_alias.html
si a esto te refieres

Comment: A eso mismo Jose!, gracias, pasa q yo el select lo estaba haciendo con * :(. Voy a probarlo. Gracias!